# Exists query for objects inside fields

Tags: elasticsearch

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html says that it is possible to query for documents that have at least one non-null value in the original field.

If the value of the original fields is an object, is it possible to query for the existence of a key in the object?

Example: a document is

```
{
    "user": {
         "name": "XY",
         "passport_id": 1234
    }
}
```

Can one make an `exists` query for `user.name`? I tried

```
{
    "query": {
        "exists" : { "field" : "user.name" }
    }
}
```

but it does not give any results.

Comment: What version of ES do you use? In 5.1 this query works for me.

Comment: You will need to map the objects as "nested":
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/nested.html

Also see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html